# Правильный класс для конвертации JSON

Tags: java, json, retrofit

Подскажите пожалуйста пытаюсь с ЯндексПереводчика получать список поддерживаемых языков. Сам ответ с сервера приходит в таком виде:

```
{
"dirs": [
    "ru-en",
    "ru-pl",
    "ru-hu",
    ...
],
"langs": {
    "ru": "русский",
    "en": "английский",
    "pl": "польский",
    ...
  }
}
```

Взяв за основу ответ с сервера [http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) Я подготовил следующие классы:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class LanguageDictionareResponse {
    @SerializedName("dirs")
    @Expose
    private List<String> dirs = null;

    @SerializedName("langs")
    @Expose
    private HashMap<CodeLanguage, Language> langs = null;

    public List<String> getDirs() {
        return dirs;
    }

    public void setDirs(List<String> dirs) {
        this.dirs = dirs;
    }

    public HashMap<CodeLanguage, Language> getLangs() {
        return langs;
    }

    public void setLangs(HashMap<CodeLanguage, Language> langs) {
        this.langs = langs;
    }
}

public class CodeLanguage {
    private String code;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}

public class Language {
    private String lang;

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
     }
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface ApiDictionare {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs")
    Call<LanguageDictionareResponse> languageDictionare(@FieldMap Map<String, String> map);
}
```

Вызов:

```
private void createRequestLanguageDictionare(){
    Call<LanguageDictionareResponse> call = apiDictionare.languageDictionare(mapJson);
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<LanguageDictionareResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LanguageDictionareResponse> call, Response<LanguageDictionareResponse> response) {
            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    response.body().toString();
                } else {
                    error();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LanguageDictionareResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            error();
        }
    });
}
```

При дебаге List dirs возвращается заполненный, а  HashMap langs = null. Я так понимаю, что не верно разбираю приходящий с сервера JSON объект.

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/20442943/3212712

Comment: С HashMap langs = null, я сам затупил, не внимательно прочитал API яндекса, и забыл указать обязательный параметр в запросе.